# Excel For Mac 2016 Scatter Plot Multiple Series in Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I would like what seems like a really simple scatter plot in Excel but I cannot find a way to do it without a lot of manual entering. I must be missing something because it seems such an obvious function for Excel to do and I also can't see previous problems like this. You help would be appreciated. Thank you.

1. I have 42 rows of data. Column B contains the name of each series. Col C is the Y variable, Col D the X variable.

[image: The image shows the first part of the data]

2. Excel won't plot this automatically, even by switching rows and columns because it doesn't understand that each series only has 1 X and 1Y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

as i understood, you should just remove (dont use) name column B in scatter chart:

[image: this is what i mean]

I have added series manualy to test if the series automatic arangement worked and seems to be ok.